# running the cmd commands from node.js program

Tags: node.js

I want to run the command "node main.js Project1" from another  js file so I used child_process.exec(command[, options][, callback]) function. This worked out successfully.Now i want to run two commands "node main.js Project1" and "node main.js Project2" one after other using this function. I tried the following code but only the first command runs.Please someone help me in doing so

```
for(var i=0;i<2;i++)
 {
    if(i==0)
    {
       var exec = require('child_process').exec,
       child;

       child = exec('node main.js Project1',
        function (error, stdout, stderr) {

         console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
         //console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
          if (error !== null) {
          console.log('exec error: ' + error);
           }
            }); 
        }
      if(i==1)
      {
       var exec = require('child_process').exec,
        child;
       child = exec('node main.js Project2',
       function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
        //console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
         if (error !== null) {
         console.log('exec error: ' + error);
      }); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have two choices ...

first choice is to use the npm module commander
npm i commander

https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander

the other choice is to continue your current approach.

NOTE THAT ...

JavaScript does not have block scope. Variables introduced within a block are scoped to the containing function or script

thus by declaring var exec twice you are redefining the variable.

also you are not using the exec callback ...

do this ...

```
   var exec = require('child_process').exec,
   child;

 // THE FUNCTION DEFINED HERE IS YOUR CALLBACK FUNCTION AND WILL BE EXECUTED AFTER YOU RUN THE COMMAND - THUS YOU WANT TO RUN THE SECOND COMMAND INSIDE THE CALLBACK
   child = exec('node main.js Project1',
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {

     console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
     //console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
      if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);



   var exec2 = require('child_process').exec,
    child;
   child = exec2('node main.js Project2',
   function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    //console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
     if (error !== null) {
     console.log('exec error: ' + error);
  }); 



       }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a loop and ifs? Keep it simple:

```
const path = require('path');
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

// it's better to build an absolute path to your script
var scriptPath = path.normalize(__dirname + '/main.js');

// the callback is the same, write it once
var fn = function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    //console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
};

var child1 = exec('node ' + scriptPath + ' Project1', fn);
var child2 = exec('node ' + scriptPath + ' Project2', fn);
```

There is the [`fork()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) function to run node scripts directly. Scripts runned like this will use the parent's output so no callback needed:

```
const path = require('path');
const child_process = require('child_process');

var scriptPath = path.normalize(__dirname + '/test.js');

var child1 = child_process.fork(scriptPath, ['Project1']);
var child2 = child_process.fork(scriptPath, ['Project2']);
```